# Populate In Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, populate

I am trying to populate Case fields(Company, End user) based on a serial number field (also the trigger) from the customer Install Base table, but somehow it is not working. Appreciate any help

```
    function beforeLoadSN() {

     // customer IB serial number
      var CustIBSerialID= custrecord_nc_ib_product_sn;
      var CustIBSerialVal=  nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_nc_ib_product_sn'); //get sn value from customer install base
      var CustIBSerialType= nlapiGetFieldType('custrecord_nc_ib_product_sn');//get type customer install base
      nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type:'+type+', FieldType: '+CustIBSerialType+', Id:'+CustIBSerialID);  
        var SN = nlapiGetFieldValue(‘custevent_qo_sp_serial_number’);//get value case SN    
        if( SN == nlapiLookupField(CustIBSerialType, CustIBSerialID, 'CustIBSerialID')) {
        //populate customer from IB
       company.nlapiSetFieldValue() = $(this).nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_nc_ib_customer.altname');
      //populate Install At  from IB
        custevent_qo_sp_installed_at.nlapiSetFieldValue() = $(this).custrecord_qo_ib_end_user.altname;     

    }

  }
```

Comment: What type of script are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).nlapiGetFieldValue`

the "$(this)" part is not needed.  If you are doing a NetSuite client side script, you can just use nlapiGetFieldValue.

Try looking at NS help for samples of client side scripts.

Comment: that what i am doing but in vain, can you write me a sample more sophisticated  and i will add other field the same way you did. thanks for your time